# How to run a github action only on a specified folder?

Tags: github-actions

I have a monorepo setup and I want to introduce CI/CD into it using Github actions. I want a separate workflow for each service. So far, I have figured out that you can use path filtering to limit when an action is run BUT I have yet to figure out how to have the action run only on a specified folder/path.

This is my current structure:

```
mono-repo --
            |
            |- services --
            |             |- service1
            |             |- service2
            |- .github --
                         |- workflows --
                                        |- service1.yaml
                                        |- service2.yaml
```

Any help is deeply appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't your action just cd into the right directory before executing the commands it has to execute?

Comment: Right. I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each step within a GitHub Actions workflow supports a parameter which [sets the working directory](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsworking-directory) for that step.

```
- name: build step
  working-directory: ./src/foo
  run: ...
```

Additionally, if your entire workflow takes place within a singular subdirectory, you can set the [default working directory](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#defaultsrun) at the top level:

```
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./src/foo
```